# Object Type conversion while doing Group By

Tags: c#, linq

I have a  List. I need to find the unique ExistingData  records by applying Group By. Following code works.

```
 var distinctItemsWorking = myCostPages
        .GroupBy(x => new { 
                             x.CostPageContent.Program, 
                             x.CostPageContent.Group, 
                             x.CostPageContent.Sequence })
        .Select(y => y.First());
```

Now I need to convert the unique list into a List. How can we achieve this conversion when we do Grouping?

**C# Method**

```
    public List<CostPage> GetCostPages(SearchEntity search, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        List<ExistingData> AllData = GetExistingData();

        var allMatchingValues = from existingDatas in AllData
                                where existingDatas.CostPageContent.Program == search.Program
                                select existingDatas;


        var query = allMatchingValues;
        List<ExistingData> currentSelectionForExistingData = query
            .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();


        //var distinctItems = currentSelectionForExistingData.GroupBy(x => new { x.CostPageContent.Program, x.CostPageContent.Group, x.CostPageContent.Sequence })
        //                    .Select(y => new CostPage()
        //                    {
        //                        CostPageContent = y.CostPageContent 
        //                    }
        //                    );

        var distinctItemsWorking = currentSelectionForExistingData.GroupBy(x => new { x.CostPageContent.Program, x.CostPageContent.Group, x.CostPageContent.Sequence })
                           .Select(y => y.First());

        List<CostPage> myCostPages = new List<CostPage>();
        foreach (ExistingData exist in distinctItemsWorking)
        {
            CostPage c = new CostPage();
            c.CostPageContent = exist.CostPageContent;
            myCostPages.Add(c);
        }

        return myCostPages;
    }
```

**Other Classes**

```
public class ExistingData
{
    public CostPageNumberContent CostPageContent { get; set; }
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
}

public class CostPage
{
    public CostPageNumberContent CostPageContent { get; set; }
}


public class CostPageNumberContent
{
    public string Program { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Sequence { get; set; }
}

public class SearchEntity
{
    public string Program { get; set; }
    public string Sequence { get; set; }
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to replace the `foreach`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I want to remove the foreach. Also the conversion should happen on the same line as Group By

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to replace the `foreach`, you can do something like this:

```
var myCostPages = currentSelectionForExistingData
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.CostPageContent.Program, x.CostPageContent.Group, 
                        x.CostPageContent.Sequence })
    .Select(y => new CostPage { CostPageContent = y.First().CostPageContent })
    .ToList();
```

Putting the creation of the `CostPage` objects into `GroupBy` would make no sense. The `Select` is the correct place to perform this conversion.